# EF Core 2.0 Relation(Null Comig)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using asp.net core 2.0 and EF core 2.0.

I have 3 class for DbSet.

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
     }



    public class Packet
    {
        [Key]
        public int PacketId { get; set; }
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public int Point{get;set;}

    }



    public class UserPacket
    {
       [Key]
        public int UserPacketId { get; set; }      
        public int ParentPersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Parent { get; set; }
        public int PacketId { get; set; }      
        public  Packet Packet { get; set; }
    }
```

And

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserPacket>().HasOne<Person>(a => a.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a=>a.ParentPersonId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserPacket>().HasOne<Person>(a => a.Owner).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a=>a.OwnerPersonId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserPacket>().HasOne<Packet>(a => a.Packet).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b=>b.PacketId);
```

This is my design for table(Not include more detail.)
var person=blabla.....

```
 var personPacket = _userPacketRepository.GetMany(a => a.OwnerPersonId == person.PersonId);
            double totalPacket = 0;
            foreach (var packet in personPacket)
            {
                totalPacket += packet.Packet.Point;
            }
```

I can select packet but for the packet.Packet comes null. Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Try to include it `_userPacketRepository.GetMany(a => a.OwnerPersonId == person.PersonId).Include(x=>x.Packet);`

Comment: @AhmedRagheb that's run Thanks. Is this future or necessary for EF Core ? Because before I didnt use Include but I can take Property (Asp.net mvc 5 and EF 6)

Comment: I will add it as an answer, Please verify it as other can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include it

```
_userPacketRepository.GetMany(a => a.OwnerPersonId == person.PersonId)
.Include(x => x.Packet);
```

You can read more about EF and their roadmap and changes from Github wiki, it is very useful 
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki